# What does '[0]' mean in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm familiar with programming but new to python:

> mem = [0] * memloadsize

what does the '[0]' represent? 
Is it a built-in array?

Comment: its just an array with one element. .. 0  .... you could do `[12]` and it would be an array of length 1 with a 12 in it ...

Comment: (Hint: tutorials are good places to learn basic language constructs!)

Comment: Good question. Btw, tutorials are only good places if you know where to look. For example "variables" "functions" "recursion". Simply a "[0]" , a construction we don't even know the name, is *not*.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `[` and `]` characters, in this context, are used to construct array literals:

```
>>> []
[]
>>> [0]
[0]
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Multiplying arrays is idiomatic, and generates an array gotten by repeating the elements in the array by the given factor:

```
>>> ['a'] * 4
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
>>> [0] * 9
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> [0, 1, 2] * 2
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

Note that `[` and `]` are also used to index into an existing array. In that case, `[0]` accesses the first element in the array:

```
>>> a = ['first', 'second', 'third']
>>> a[0]
'first'
>>> a[2]
'third'
>>>
```

Comment: This is just such a fantastic answer to such a simple question. Very impressed.

Answer (score 11):

It just means a one element `list` containing just a 0. Multiplying by `memloadsize` gives you a `list` of `memloadsize` zeros.

Comment: Strictly speaking it gives you a list of `memloadsize` references to *the same zero*. The difference is irrelevant for things like numbers, but it is *vital* too keep this in mind if you use list multiplication, because that's almost never what you want if the things in the list might be mutable.

Comment: Thanks you! I finally understood after jump on the terminal and practicing: mem = [1] * 10

Answer (score 3):

This command is conceptually equivalent to this:

```
mem = []
for i in xrange(memloadsize):
    mem.append(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now that I know what this means I understand what your code.